# Linear inequalities with random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose i have two linear inequalities as follows: $X + Y > k_1$ and $X > k_2$ where X and Y are two random variables that follows a certain probabilty distribution, for example $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$ and $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{R}, k_1 > k_2$. How can i compute the probability $P(X + Y > k_1,X > k_2)$? Clearly the two variables are dependent and i cannot compute the probability as the product of the probabilities. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you say "clearly the two variables are dependent" when no mention of dependence or independence between $X$ and $Y$ is given?  In general, you cannot compute the probability unless you know a joint distribution or joint density for $(X,Y)$.  Assuming you know a joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, just integrate that over all $(x,y)$ that satisfy $x+y>k_1, x>k_2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ have a joint density $p(x,y)$ you can just evaluate the double integral:

$$ P(X+Y > k_1,X>k_2) = \int_{k_2}^\infty\int_{k_1-x}^\infty p(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x. $$